# How to keep display always connected when display is off in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, mac, hdmi, htpc

I've got a Mac Mini connected to my TV for use as a HTPC and whenever I shut off the TV, the Mac has noticed that a display is disconnected. Normally with most machines this isn't an issue, but with this Mac disconnecting the display for long periods of time or frequently results in a massive degradation in performance.

Additionally, upon turning on the TV it takes a minute or so before the machine actually connects to the display.

Is there a way to trick macOS to keep this display alive even when it's "disconnected"? I am using the HDMI port on the Mini.

Answer (score 0):

I use Amphetamine,

(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12)

and it's never failed me

Comment: how to you configure it ?

Comment: I usually select indefinitely and just turn it off when I'm done

Answer (score 0):

I just tell the Mac to put the display to sleep before turning off the TV.

A quick way to do this is to set up a 'Hot Corner' set to 'Put Display to Sleep' on the 'Screen Saver' tab of the 'Desktop and Screen Saver' page of the 'System Preferences' (click the 'Hot Corners' button at the bottom of the page).